# Adding n-number of due date fields and descriptions to Epics and Stories

Tags: user-stories, jira, epics

In an existing project, the team is attaching tasks directly to Epics.  I would like to introduce stories to the workflow and n-number of key dates to either the Epics or features.

For this, I would like the PMs to be able to add date/owner/description fields by hitting a "+" or something like that.

The use case is that projects will have different milestone dates, owners, etc.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: I don’t think JIRA fits this use case. You might be able to extend it, but it’s fundamentally a ticketing system, and the ticketing model model isn’t natively multivalued.

Comment: In that case, create separate tickets for every due date, listing them in the Epic? Actually not tickets but stories?